# Using Type.GetType() function to get the type of the class from the different namespace

Tags: c#

I want to call a class and its method with the name of the class and the method name will be known at run time. the class i want to call is a in a different project ClassLibrary. .The namespace of the class which is to be called i have added reference of it to my current project. and wrote the following code to call.

```
Type CalledType = Type.GetType("ClassLibraryLocation." + ClassName);

MethodInfo info = CalledType.GetMethod(FunctionName);

Object new_obj = Activator.CreateInstance(CalledType);

Object retval = info.Invoke(new_obj, new object[] { "ABC" });
Console.WriteLine(retval);

//ClassLibraryLocation is an anather namespace for which the reference is added.

//ClassName is the name of the class present in the  ClassLibraryLocation  namespace

//FunctionName is the name of the function present in the  ClassName Class
```

But The Type.GetType() Method returns Null CalledType

Please Help

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Type.GetType` requires an assembly name unless the type is in `mscorlib` or the calling assembly.

Instead, you should find the `Assembly` instance that contains your type (eg, `typeof(SomethingElse).Assembly`), then call `GetType` on it.

Comment: Actually when I call The class which is in the same namespace from which  the calling is done it work properly. But when the class moved to different namespace the Type.GetType("ClassLibraryLocation." + ClassName); code fails

Comment: You mean _assembly_, not namespace.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx

Comment: I am elaborating my question, let say in namespace ABC i have two classes A and B, In The Class A in main function I used the Type.GetType(ABC.B) to get the type of B and call its functions it worked correctly. but the i had to move the class B to Different namespace say CDE and called it from ABC namespace using the similar code.but the Type.GetType("ABC." + B); function returning null.

Comment: I know.  You mean **assembly**, not namespace.  You need to search the correct assembly for the type.

Answer (score 1):

I am using the below function to perform the call

```
public static Object ExecuteBLMethod(string ClassName, string Method, object[] args)
    {
        Type _Class = Type.GetType("BusinessLayer." + ClassName + ", BL, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken="xxxx-xx");
        if (_Class != null)
        {
            object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(_Class);
            if (obj != null)
                return _Class.InvokeMember(Method, BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, obj, args);
        }
        return null;
    }
```